# How to get only 10% records of each group by column?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Let me explain whole problem.
Suppose i have a table like shown below

```
    Id                   Box    Folder   Status 
    -------------------- ------ -------- ----------
    493                  77777  9995     1          
    494                  77777  9996     1          
    494                  77777  9996     1          
    494                  77777  9996     1          
    494                  77777  9996     1          
    494                  77777  9996     1 
    494                  77777  9996     1 
    494                  77777  9996     1     
    494                  77777  9996     1     
    494                  77777  9996     1     
    497                  88888  9999     1          
    498                  88888  0000     0       
    498                  88888  0000     0       
    498                  88888  0000     0       
    498                  88888  0000     0       
    495                  99999  9997     1          
    496                  99999  9998     1          
    496                  99999  9998     1          
    497                  88888  9999     1          
    498                  88888  0000018  0   
    498                  88888  0000018  0   
    498                  88888  0000018  0          
    499                  66666  0000020  1          
    502                  66666  1000     1
```

Now i need result like get 10% records of each "boxNo"

for example boxno "77777" have 10 records. 10% of 10 record is 1 record. so only 1 record should be visible.

in my mind only way to do it with cursor and temp table.
Anyone can suggest either and simpler way to get these kind of result ?

Comment: What if any boxno have less than 10 rows or only 1?

Comment: @Ankit Bajpai in that case, minimum 1 record should be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with window functions.  Although there is `ntile()` and `percentile() functions, I would just do the counts explicitly:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by box order by newid()) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by box) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 0.1 * cnt;
```

You may want to ensure that you get at least one record.  If so:

```
where seqnum <= 0.1 * cnt or seqnum = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get data by using `TOP PERCENT`

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (Id INT, Box VARCHAR(10), Folder VARCHAR(10) , Status INT)
INSERT INTO @Table 
VALUES
(493,'77777','9995',1),
(494,'77777','9996',1),
(494,'77777','9996',1),
(494,'77777','9996',1),
(494,'77777','9996',1),
(494,'77777','9996',1), 
(494,'77777','9996',1), 
(494,'77777','9996',1),
(494,'77777','9996',1),
(494,'77777','9996',1),
(497,'88888','9999',1),
(498,'88888','0000',0),
(498,'88888','0000',0),
(498,'88888','0000',0),
(498,'88888','0000',0),
(495,'99999','9997',1),
(496,'99999','9998',1),
(496,'99999','9998',1),
(497,'88888','9999',1),
(498,'88888','0000018',0),
(498,'88888','0000018',0),
(498,'88888','0000018',0),
(499,'66666','0000020',1),
(502,'66666','1000',1)

SELECT X.* FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Box FROM @Table) T
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT * FROM @Table WHERE Box = T.Box ORDER BY ID) X
```

Result:

```
Id          Box        Folder     Status
----------- ---------- ---------- -----------
499         66666      0000020    1
493         77777      9995       1
497         88888      9999       1
495         99999      9997       1
```